# How do I view and modify metadata of audio and video files?

Tags: audio, file-metadata

I want to be able to set metadata, primarily to files in my music library, so that I can use it like tags, to sort them as needed (directory-based organization is, I think obsolete).

How do I do this?

Comment: Depends on the (container) format of your files. You should first look at [`exiftool`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool)

Comment: @ridgy They're mainly *m4a*, *ogg* or *weba* files

Comment: Following the link in my comment, you will see that m4a, ogg and webm (which also includes weba) is supported by exiftool, at least to read the metadata. The rest is scripting...

Comment: For writing tags, you can try [EasyTag](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG); works for .m4a and .ogg, don't know about .weba.

Comment: I found this thing called [mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)